# Increase Intellij delay for autocomplete popup on typing dot

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to increase the time/delay it takes for the pop up that shows the various autocomplete options on typing a '.' or a method or class name. I couldn't find it anywhere in the options in IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.3.

That popup is becoming way too distracting for me. There are times when it is helpful but I don't need it most of the time for typing simple stuff like '.get(),.put()' etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No setting for that at the moment:

- [IDEABKL-7256](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7256) Code Completion autopopup delay

The suggested workaround is to disable the automatic completion and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> when needed, but it may not be a satisfactory solution for everyone.

Comment: 2022 and still not possible.

Comment: Ouch! Still no activity 2 years later.